# Is quotient module finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Suppose $R$ be any ring containing left ideal $I$. Then $I$ is submodule of $R$, so $R/I$ is R-module. My question is, is $R/I$ always a finitely generated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote $\bar r$ the class of $r\in R$ modulo $I$. Then
$$
\bar r=\overline{r\cdot1}=r\cdot\bar1
$$
i.e. $R/I$ is generated as $R$-module by $\bar1$.

More generally, if $M$ is a $R$-module generated by $m_1,...,m_s$, then the classes $\bar m_1,...,\bar m_s$ generate $M/IM$ over $R$.